# Problems with a react application deployed on k8s

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes

I have a problem with a simple react app that was created using `npx create-react-app react-app`. Once deployed on k8s, I got this:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

However, if I would to `kubectl port-forward` to the pod and view the app at localhost:3000 (container's pod is at 3000, cluster ip service listening on 3000 and forwarding to 3000) no problem at all.

The ingress routing looks to be fine as I can get to other services to work within the cluster but not to the app. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: react-app-deployment
  # namespace: gitlab-managed-apps
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: react-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: react-app
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: simpleweb-token-namespace
      containers:
      - name: react-app
        image: registry.gitlab.com/mttlong/sample/react-app
        env:
        - name: "PORT"
          value: "3000"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

Cluster ip service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: react-app-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: react-app
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.15.3-alpine as builder
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
EXPOSE 3000
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Ingress Service:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
  name: orion-ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2

spec:
  rules:
    - host: horizon.zeezum.com
      http: 
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: react-app-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: simple-api-nodeport-service
              servicePort: 3050
```

Comment: can you provide the deployment  yaml

Comment: can you put whole text to error ?

Comment: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://horizon.zeezum.com/static/css/main.d1b05096.chunk.css".
2.964cd682.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
main.42af1276.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: Hi, I had the same issue, did u find any solution? or the root cause?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Problem still persists.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue as you have described. I solved it by splitting up the Ingress for the front-end and the API.

In your case this would look something like this:

Front-end ingress service (without rewrite target):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: orion-ingress-frontend-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: horizon.zeezum.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: react-app-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 3000
```

Back-end ingress service (with the /$2 rewrite-target):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
    name: orion-ingress-backend-service
    annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
    rules:
        - host: horizon.zeezum.com
            http: 
                paths:
                    - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
                        backend:
                            serviceName: simple-api-nodeport-service
                            servicePort: 3050
```

The rest of you configuration should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2` this line and it should work

Comment: I think this means you won't be able to access the API anymore and that you will receive 405 errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the result of a 404 page or a redirect to a page that serves regular html instead of the expected JavaScript files. (A HTML page starts with `<html>` or a `<!DOCTYPE...>` therefore the `<` as unexpected token)

Make sure that you have correctly build the image and you access the page correctly. You can verify by manually accessing the URL with the browser or look into the network tab of your browser development tools to inspect the response.
(I assume that either you have cached the index.html and try to access old assets, check your cache header, or that the paths to not match. In that case inspect your image and access the URLs manually)

Comment: I'm getting 200 response for the GET methods. As for the HTML page, this is a production build of the React app ie. the code has been transpiled into a build folder along with the assets. Not sure how else to proceed.

Comment: Do you get the expected javascript or the index page (html) as response?

Comment: I got the index.html as the response.

Comment: So this seems to be related to your specific image, not kubernetes or react. Try the (exact!) image locally with docker or inspect the content (f.e. with dive) to make sure it contains your application. (f.e. .dockerignore is a common culprit)

Comment: I had tried running locally with 'docker run' before deploying to k8s without any problems. Also, after deploying to k8s, I had no problem port-forwarding to the pod and the react app had no problems. It's only when I try to access it via the URL.

Comment: How do you expose the container to the outside?

Comment: I started with creating a GKE Loadbalancer, using NGINX Ingress controller. Then created an Ingress object (see Ingress service above).

Comment: The rewrite in the ingress definition rewrites all requests of files to the root url since there is no capture group in the non-api route.

Comment: So what would help in this situation.

Comment: I created a LoadBalancer and pointed its ip straight to the app's container. That works but I'm still at a loss as to why I can't use the Ingress controller to route to that container.

Comment: I suggest to use two ingress instances: One for the api route only, one for the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing. I got rid of the Ingress altogether, and in my Service yaml file changed my Service to `type: Nodeport` and added the fields `protocol: TCP` and `nodePort: <insert nodeport>` under each port.

I got the values ofthe nodeports by running `kubectl expose deployment <insert deployment name> --type=NodePort --name=example-service`. Which creates a service and assigns the ports. You can then run `kubectl describe services example-service` to display all the nodeport values. You can then copy the values to your Service yaml file.

When its all running you would access the website from the browser using the nodeport that was generated, ie `localhost:31077`for example, and not the actual port `3000`.

I then changed any url routes I had to use the nodeport instead of the actual ports and boom.