# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in app.js in Gcloud

Tags: laravel, vue.js, deployment, gcloud

I'm very new to Gcloud after 4 attempts I deployed local Laravel + Vue Project to Gcloud. It worked fine in local env, but the app showing blank page after deployment and the console showing below error message. 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` app.js.

Even the resource files also not visible.

App link: https://fluted-vehicle-277421.el.r.appspot.com/

Can anyone suggest what went wrong?

Comment: You need to build your app i mean

Answer (score 0):

This error typically gets thrown when in js file  you have put html.

Try checking if you have html inside js file and remove it.

Comment: app.js doesn't have any HTML, it vue core file.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error you mentioned in your post, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60238331/11821225), this error is most likely the result of a 404 page or a redirect to a page that serves regular html instead of the JavaScript files.

On the other hand, I am not sure if you deployed a new version but currently, the error I see if I go to your site is "There is no existing directory at "C:\xampp\htdocs\LMS_project\storage\logs" and its not buildable: Permission denie". So, as I can see these errors are because you are not change correctly the paths in your app. You need to ensure the right paths in order to avoid this errors.

Comment: Initially, I used standard environment then I got Uncaught SyntaxError. Now I redeployed with a flexible environment and caught up with ```There is no existing directory at "C:\xampp\htdocs\LMS_project\storage\logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied```

Comment: app.yaml ```runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

env_variables:
   APP_LOG: errorlog
   APP_KEY: base64:izKSrj0gIKtd23gpy2fEQ8QJztUprH220Un4mxUtFOM=
   APP_STORAGE: /tmp
   VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
   CACHE_DRIVER: database
   SESSION_DRIVER: database
   DB_DATABASE: DB_NAME
   DB_USERNAME: DB_USER
   DB_PASSWORD: DB_PASSWORD
   DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME"```

Comment: As I commented before, the error you are facing is because you are using the paths you should use locally. If you see the error, App Engine is searching for "C:\xampp\htdocs\LMS_project\storage\logs". This is not in GCP, that is the reason why you must change all that type of references. On the other hand, I noticed that the current error is 404 code. Does your site is enable? if so, does your site have a handler?